# Pandas interpolate throws an invalid fill method error after version 0.24

Tags: python, pandas

The `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate()` method is throwing this error when using the `method='time'` argument:

```sh
Error: Invalid fill method. Expecting pad (ffill) or backfill (bfill). Got time
```

This only started happening after `pandas` updated to version 0.24, which seems to have changed some implementation. Code that used to work breads with version 0.24 or greater.

I thought it might have to do with the data types of the columns, meaning that if the `DataFrame` included non-numeric columns the interpolation would fail. That doesn't seems to be the case though, since I've recently run into this again with a purely numeric `DataFrame`.

I believe I got this to work at some point, but I can't remember how (other than messing with data types). This is problematic because my existing codebase has to pin pandas to 0.23 for the functionality to work.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who has a similar issue, I also got this error due to the new pandas types after `1.1.x`.

For me, the problem was that I was trying to interpolate data that was an `Int64` type and it would only let me do a forward or backward fill. In previous versions of `pandas` this wasn't a problem as the type automatically be recast to float to complete the interpolation.

This is not the case anymore -- you need to explicitly cast to float and then you can interpolate. Yes, it is completely unnecessary type safety. Yes, it is a horrible error message.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error while my DataFrame consists out of float and datetime data. I found that the error occurs with datetime columns that have timezone information. When converting these columns to naïve datetime format the error was gone.

Comment: Interesting, that's pretty similar to my use case. There definitely seems to be issues with certain data types that didn't exist in previous versions of the software. In one case I was just being silly and forgot to make a `DatetimeIndex`, but I've run into this even when I do have a proper `DatetimeIndex`, which is when I realized the data type issues. Seems like a combination of these strategies should resolve this error in most cases.